# FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/not-found] Some requested document was not found.)

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
onConfirm: (date)async{
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('orders')
    .doc(order['orderid']).update(
     {
       'deliverystatus':'shipping',
       'deliverydate':date,
    }, 
  );
}
```

FireBase screenshot

[image: FireBase screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to load the document by its document ID, but in the screenshot you share the value of the `orderid` field (`250fa...`) does **not** match the document ID (`CwdHE...`) in the middle column.

If you know the document ID, you can pass that to the `doc()` method instead, and keep the rest of your code the same.

If you don't know the document ID, you can [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) to loop up the document based on its `orderid`. Based on the sample code in that link, it'd look something like:

```
db.collection("orders").where("orderid", isEqualTo: order['orderid']).get().then(
      (querySnapshot) {
        print("Successfully completed");
        for (var docSnapshot in querySnapshot.docs) {
          print('${docSnapshot.id} => ${docSnapshot.data()}');
        }
      },
      onError: (e) => print("Error completing: $e"),
    );
```

---

Do consider though if you really need to have a different document ID and order ID. If your `orderid` values are always going to be unique in the `orders` collection, it might be easier to use the `orderid` as the document ID - or to use the document ID that Firestore generates as the order ID.

Comment: Frank van Puffelen. Thank you so much for your response. You are absolutely right. It fixed my issue.